# i need to convert this to add nother condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

fllowing code  i need to converting with adding nother condition.i need to get flowing data row which have maximum value to nother database column name startmile(highest startmile)(table name is fourm1data columns are id,name username,startmile and date).There will be few rows which have similar user name i need to get certain data row which have highest startmile value.

```
$username = $_POST["username"];


   $statement = mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT * From fourm1details where username=? "); 

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
```

Comment: You need to show us your table structures, some sample data and the expected output from that sample data.

Comment: able name -fourm1_data(id -int,name-varchar,username-varchar,startmile-int,date-va‌​rchar); expected output(1,tony,tony123,4567,2017/june/01)

Comment: Please update your question with the extra info (formatted) instead of in a comment.